# Get twitter status message by id

Tags: php, twitter

When i send status on twitter, i have response with id of this status. Someone know, can i get status meesage by id, from response.

```
 $update_status = $twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $tweet_msg));
 temp = $update_status->response;

 $twitterInfo = $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
 $twitterInfo->response;
 $message_id = $twitterInfo->status->id_str;
```

in `$message_id` i have an id of status message

Comment: which wrapper are you using for twitter api?

Comment: I use Epic, already found an answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the url for twitter api specs:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid